# how to load mask while the grid is double clicked to wait for the detail window

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member I am having one problem while using the loadMask property of the extjs 4.0.2a. Actually I am having one grid which on click open the window with detail information.

As my detail window takes more time to come on screen, so I just decided to make use of the loadMask property of Extjs. But don't know why the loading message is not shown when I double click the grid row and after some time the detail window is shown on the screen.

on grid double click I am executing the below code

```
projectEditTask: function(grid,cell,row,col,e) {
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading.."});        
myMask.show();
var win = this.getProjectGanttwindow();  
win.on('show', myMask.hide, myMask);   
}
```

but don't know the loading is not displayed and after waiting for some moment my window is shown correctly.

I just want when I double click the grid Loading message should be displayed and after when the window is load completely Loading message should be dissapear and detail window should be viewed.

when I made the changes as per you said the loading message is displayed but my window is not opened yet. below is the code of window I am trying to open

**my projectGanttwindow is**

```
Ext.define('gantt.view.projectmgt.projectGanttwindow' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.projectganttwindow',
    requires: ['gantt.view.projectmgt.projectGanttpanel'],
    editform:1,
    id: 'projectganttwindow',
    title: 'Project Management',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%', 
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    isWindow: true,
    flex:1,  
    isModal: true,
    constrain: true, 
    maximizable: true,  
     stateful: false,
     projectId: null, // this will be set before showing window

     listeners: {
         hide: function() {
            alert('hide');
           //var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('taskStore').destroyStore();
           //Ext.destroy(store);
           //store.destroyStore();
           console.log('Done destroying');
         }
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.layoutConfig = {
            align: 'stretch'
        };
        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'projectganttpanel',
            allowBlank: false
        }];

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on({
            scope: me,
            beforeshow: me.onBeforeShow
        });
    },

    onBeforeShow: function() {      
        var projectId = this.projectId;
        console.log('BEFOR SHOW ::'+projectId);
        if(projectId != null) {
            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('taskStore');
            store.load({
                params: {'id': projectId}
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Loading message is showing correctly for me. I don's see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: actually my window takes more than 20 secs to load so till that time I want to show that loading mask message. But I didn't show me the loading message and the detailed window load after 20-25 secs. So is there any way I can set the timeout of the loadMask ??

Comment: I don't quite get it. You load mask is not visible or you don't know how to hide it after window is loaded?

Comment: **my load mask is not visible** and after some time the detailed window comes successfully. so is there any solution ??

Comment: I don't know why your mask is not visible. It works just fine for me. To hide mask, you need to call `hide` method after window is loaded. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/6S499/

Comment: @Lolo I made the changes to my question as per you said but still the same problem. Any other tricks you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function loadMask(el,flag,msg){
var Mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.get(el), {msg:msg});
if(flag)
    Mask.show();
else
    Mask.hide();
```

}

When u click on grid call this function

//Enable mask message

`loadMask(Ext.getBody(),'1','Please wait...');`

After pop loaded call

//Disable mask Message

`loadMask(Ext.getBody(),'','Please wait...');`